# Actual date cannot be extracted

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the date and time of a news article. after scraping data I got some different dates from the actual date of the news article. as an example the actual date of the article published was `" Heute, 07:40 "` in German ("heute" means "today"), but after scraping it gives `"Heute, vor -60 Minuten"`.

```
l = 'https://kurier.at/sport/tennis/auftaktniederlage-fuer-dominic-thiem-in-rio-de-janeiro/402336705'
page = requests.get(l)
b = soup(page.content)
print(b.findAll('span',{'class' : 'article-meta-date ng-star-inserted'}))
print(l)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have selected wrong element.
Try below css selector to get the time.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

l = 'https://kurier.at/sport/tennis/auftaktniederlage-fuer-dominic-thiem-in-rio-de-janeiro/402336705'
page = requests.get(l)
b = soup(page.content, 'html.parser')
print(b.select_one('p.article-header-leadText-date.ng-star-inserted').text.strip())
```

you have to use `.text` to get the value and `.strip()` to removed any `leading` or `trailing` spaces.

Output:

```
 Heute, 07:40 AM
```